# How can i identify each components CPU Usage in Siebel Server?

Tags: components, cpu-usage, siebel

How can i identify each components CPU usage in Siebel server, is there any list command available to monitor CPU usage to component, If not kindly let me know how i can achieve this

Thanks,
Ramachandran.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use the following command in server manager - "list procs" .
This will give you a list of all the components and their process id's. You can use this process id to track the CPU usage using conventional methods.